Chainlink Functions BASE Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted
I'm testing Chainlink Functions GET request on Base network, I'm following this tutorial: https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/getting-started
I just copy and pasted the contract code and edited the router and DON id to Base's information. I used the correction subscription id and it's funded and added the correct consumer.
But I'm getting this error when I try to do the sendRequest function inside the smart contract:

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Error happened while trying to execute a function inside a smart
contract Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted

Reproducible code for BASE:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.19;

import {FunctionsClient} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/v1_0_0/FunctionsClient.sol";
import {ConfirmedOwner} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import {FunctionsRequest} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/v1_0_0/libraries/FunctionsRequest.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/resources/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * @title GettingStartedFunctionsConsumer
 * @notice This is an example contract to show how to make HTTP requests using Chainlink
 * @dev This contract uses hardcoded values and should not be used in production.
 */
contract GettingStartedFunctionsConsumer is FunctionsClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using FunctionsRequest for FunctionsRequest.Request;

    // State variables to store the last request ID, response, and error
    bytes32 public s_lastRequestId;
    bytes public s_lastResponse;
    bytes public s_lastError;

    // Custom error type
    error UnexpectedRequestID(bytes32 requestId);

    // Event to log responses
    event Response(
        bytes32 indexed requestId,
        string character,
        bytes response,
        bytes err
    );

    // Router address - Hardcoded for Sepolia
    // Check to get the router address for your supported network https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/supported-networks
    address router = 0xf9B8fc078197181C841c296C876945aaa425B278;

    // JavaScript source code
    // Fetch character name from the Star Wars API.
    // Documentation: https://swapi.info/people
    string source =
        "const characterId = args[0];"
        "const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({"
        "url: `https://swapi.info/api/people/${characterId}/`"
        "});"
        "if (apiResponse.error) {"
        "throw Error('Request failed');"
        "}"
        "const { data } = apiResponse;"
        "return Functions.encodeString(data.name);";

    //Callback gas limit
    uint32 gasLimit = 30000000;

    // donID - Hardcoded for Sepolia
    // Check to get the donID for your supported network https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/supported-networks
    bytes32 donID = 0x66756e2d626173652d6d61696e6e65742d310000000000000000000000000000;

    // State variable to store the returned character information
    string public character;

    /**
     * @notice Initializes the contract with the Chainlink router address and sets the contract owner
     */
    constructor() FunctionsClient(router) ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {}

    /**
     * @notice Sends an HTTP request for character information
     * @param subscriptionId The ID for the Chainlink subscription
     * @param args The arguments to pass to the HTTP request
     * @return requestId The ID of the request
     */
    function sendRequest(
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        string[] calldata args
    ) external onlyOwner returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        FunctionsRequest.Request memory req;
        req.initializeRequestForInlineJavaScript(source); // Initialize the request with JS code
        if (args.length > 0) req.setArgs(args); // Set the arguments for the request

        // Send the request and store the request ID
        s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(
            req.encodeCBOR(),
            subscriptionId,
            gasLimit,
            donID
        );

        return s_lastRequestId;
    }

    /**
     * @notice Callback function for fulfilling a request
     * @param requestId The ID of the request to fulfill
     * @param response The HTTP response data
     * @param err Any errors from the Functions request
     */
    function fulfillRequest(
        bytes32 requestId,
        bytes memory response,
        bytes memory err
    ) internal override {
        if (s_lastRequestId != requestId) {
            revert UnexpectedRequestID(requestId); // Check if request IDs match
        }
        // Update the contract's state variables with the response and any errors
        s_lastResponse = response;
        character = string(response);
        s_lastError = err;

        // Emit an event to log the response
        emit Response(requestId, character, s_lastResponse, s_lastError);
    }
}

Now test doing the sendRequest function. It gives the error for me.

Please update the donID per our docs: https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/supported-networks
Currently, you are using 0x66756e2d626173652d6d61696e6e65742d310000000000000000000000000000, but the appropriate donID is 0x66756e2d626173652d7365706f6c69612d310000000000000000000000000000.
Please let me know if this resolves your inquiry. If not, then we can debug further, but an invalid donID will disable the contract's ability to send a request successfully.

The callback gas limit should be less than or equal to 300000.  So, replace this:
uint32 gasLimit = 30000000;

With:
uint32 gasLimit = 300_000;


I tried this already and did it again, but still I get the same error. This error doesn't occur when on Sepolia network by the way, just on BASE for now

By Sepolia, do you mean Base Sepolia or Eth Sepolia?
